# How to build opencv java libs from source code?

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to build opencv java libs for android with opencv 4.1.0 source code. I tried to use `build_sdk.py` of android platform of the source code. I used `jre` of `Android Studio` through `export JAVA_HOME=/AndroidStudio/jre` and changed `CMakeLists.txt` of `opencv`:

```
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS        "Build shared libraries (.dll/.so) instead of static ones (.lib/.a)" ON )
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_opencv_apps        "Build utility applications (used for example to train classifiers)" (NOT ANDROID AND NOT WINRT) IF (NOT APPLE_FRAMEWORK) )
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_opencv_js          "Build JavaScript bindings by Emscripten" OFF )
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS   "Build Android projects providing .apk files" OFF )
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES   "Build examples for Android platform"         OFF )
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_DOCS               "Create build rules for OpenCV Documentation" OFF  IF (NOT WINRT AND NOT APPLE_FRAMEWORK))
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_EXAMPLES           "Build all examples"                          OFF )
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_PACKAGE            "Enables 'make package_source' command"       ON  IF NOT WINRT)
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_PERF_TESTS         "Build performance tests"                     NOT INSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB  IF (NOT APPLE_FRAMEWORK) )
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_TESTS              "Build accuracy & regression tests"           NOT INSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB  IF (NOT APPLE_FRAMEWORK) )
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_WITH_DEBUG_INFO    "Include debug info into release binaries ('OFF' means default settings)" OFF )
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT    "Enables use of statically linked CRT for statically linked OpenCV" ON IF MSVC )
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_WITH_DYNAMIC_IPP   "Enables dynamic linking of IPP (only for standalone IPP)" OFF )
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB       "Create Java wrapper exporting all functions of OpenCV library (requires static build of OpenCV modules)" ANDROID IF NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_ANDROID_SERVICE    "Build OpenCV Manager for Google Play" OFF IF ANDROID )
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_CUDA_STUBS         "Build CUDA modules stubs when no CUDA SDK" OFF  IF (NOT APPLE_FRAMEWORK) )
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_JAVA               "Enable Java support"                         ON )
```

`android SDK` and `ndk` are used from `Android Studio` and after running `./build_sdk.py --ndk-path /Android/SDK/ndk/20.1.5948944 --sdk-path /Android/SDK /opencv /download/opencv`, the directory `OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/java/` only has a empty directory `javadoc`. What's wrong with my configuration? How to build java libs from source code correctly?